# RSpec,Capybara,Poltergeist: Unable to find angular app content in test scenarios where ng-app defined on a div or Body instead of HTML tag

Tags: angularjs, ruby, rspec, capybara, poltergeist

I am unable to get any content of page in Rspec test scenarios for ng-view or ui-view when ng-app defined on div or body instead of HTML tag. But in case ng-app is defined on HTML tag content, it is visible for ng-view.

**capybara_config.rb**

```
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
require_relative '../rack/rack_config'

Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  options = {debug: false, js_errors: false, timeout: 180, phantomjs_logger: StringIO.new, logger: nil,
             extensions: [File.expand_path("../../js_libraries/jquery.js", __FILE__), File.expand_path("../../js_libraries/jquery-ui.min.js", __FILE__),
                          File.expand_path("../../js_libraries/jquery-ui.min.css", __FILE__), File.expand_path("../../js_libraries/jquery-ui.theme.min.css", __FILE__)],
             phantomjs_options: ['--load-images=no', '--ignore-ssl-errors=yes']}
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app,options)
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false
Capybara.default_wait_time = 5
```

**spec_helper.rb**

```
require 'rspec/core'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Capybara::DSL
end
```

**angular_test_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'
require_relative '../config/capybara/capybara_config'

describe "Employee Index Page UI content" , js: true  do
  it "employee index page " do
    visit('https://app.employes.nl')
    puts(page.body)
  end
end
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem "rspec"
gem "capybara"
gem "poltergeist"
```

On code inspect of [**app.employes.nl**](http://app.employes.nl)

```
   <body ng-app="employeesApp" class="ng-scope"> <!-- uiView:  --><ui-view class="ng-scope"><div class="container ng-scope"> <!-- uiView:  --><ui-view class="ng-scope"><div class="container-small ng-scope"> <div class="panel panel-default"> <div class="panel-body"> <form class="form-signin ng-pristine ng-valid-email ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" ng-submit="login()"> <div class="row"> <div class="col-xs-12 text-center"> <img style="height: 2em" src="images/LogoEmployes.52a47633.png"> </div> </div> <hr> <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Je emailadres</label> <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-empty ng-valid-email ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" placeholder="Je e-mailadres" ng-model="formData.email" required="" autofocus="" style=""> <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Je wachtwoord</label> <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" placeholder="Je wachtwoord" ng-model="formData.password" required=""> <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Inloggen</button> </form> <p class="text-muted small text-center"> <a href="#/signup" ui-sref="signup">Nog geen account?</a> | <a href="#/reset-password" ui-sref="reset-password">Wachtwoord vergeten?</a> </p> </div> </div> </div></ui-view> </div> <footer class="footer ng-scope"> <div class="container"> <p class="text-center text-muted small"> © Employes B.V. 2016 | <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#help">Heb je vragen? Neem contact met ons op.</a> </p> </div> </footer> <!-- Contact modal--> <div class="modal fade ng-scope" id="help" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"> <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm"> <div class="modal-content"> <div class="modal-header"> <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button> <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Neem contact op</h4> </div> <div class="modal-body"> <div class="row"> <div class="col-md-12 text-center"> <p>Heb je vragen, bel of mail gerust!</p> <a href="mailto:info@employes.nl">Mail ons</a><br>of<br> <a href="callto:0537893036">Tel. 053-789 30 36</a> </div> </div> </div> <div class="modal-footer"> </div> </div> </div> </div></ui-view> <!-- Full page loader. --> <div class="pg-loading-screen pg-loading ng-hide" style="background-color: #E6E6E6" ng-show="isAppLoading"> <div class="pg-loading-inner"> <div class="pg-loading-center-outer"> <div class="pg-loading-center-middle"> <h1 class="pg-loading-logo-header"> <img style="height: 1.5em" class="pg-loading-logo" src="images/LogoEmployes.52a47633.png"> </h1> <div class="pg-loading-html pg-loaded"> <p class="loading-message"></p> <div class="sk-circle"> <div class="sk-circle1 sk-child"></div> <div class="sk-circle2 sk-child"></div> <div class="sk-circle3 sk-child"></div> <div class="sk-circle4 sk-child"></div> <div class="sk-circle5 sk-child"></div> <div class="sk-circle6 sk-child"></div> <div class="sk-circle7 sk-child"></div> <div class="sk-circle8 sk-child"></div> <div class="sk-circle9 sk-child"></div> <div class="sk-circle10 sk-child"></div> <div class="sk-circle11 sk-child"></div> <div class="sk-circle12 sk-child"></div> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://widget.intercom.io/widget/{app_id}"></script><script src="https://drrjhlchpvi7e.cloudfront.net/libs/stamplay-js-sdk/1.3.3/stamplay.min.js"></script> <script src="scripts/vendor.11815825.js"></script> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-i18n/1.5.0/angular-locale_nl-nl.js"></script> <script src="scripts/scripts.9367f845.js"></script> <!-- Snippet for Intercom.io --> <script type="text/javascript">(function(){var w=window;var ic=w.Intercom;if(typeof ic==="function"){ic('reattach_activator');ic('update',intercomSettings);}else{var d=document;var i=function(){i.c(arguments)};i.q=[];i.c=function(args){i.q.push(args)};w.Intercom=i;function l(){var s=d.createElement('script');s.type='text/javascript';s.async=true;
s.src='https://widget.intercom.io/widget/{app_id}';
var x=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];x.parentNode.insertBefore(s,x);}if(w.attachEvent){w.attachEvent('onload',l);}else{w.addEventListener('load',l,false);}}})()</script>  <iframe style="display: none;"></iframe></body>
```

But got following output on angular_test_spec.rb execution:

```
<body ng-app="employeesApp"> <ui-view></ui-view> <!-- Full page loader. --> <div class="pg-loading-screen pg-loading" style="background-color: #E6E6E6" ng-show="isAppLoading"> <div class="pg-loading-inner"> <div class="pg-loading-center-outer"> <div class="pg-loading-center-middle"> <h1 class="pg-loading-logo-header"> <img style="height: 1.5em" class="pg-loading-logo" src="images/LogoEmployes.52a47633.png"> </h1> <div class="pg-loading-html pg-loaded"> <p class="loading-message"></p> <div class="sk-circle"> <div class="sk-circle1 sk-child"></div> <div class="sk-circle2 sk-child"></div> <div class="sk-circle3 sk-child"></div> <div class="sk-circle4 sk-child"></div> <div class="sk-circle5 sk-child"></div> <div class="sk-circle6 sk-child"></div> <div class="sk-circle7 sk-child"></div> <div class="sk-circle8 sk-child"></div> <div class="sk-circle9 sk-child"></div> <div class="sk-circle10 sk-child"></div> <div class="sk-circle11 sk-child"></div> <div class="sk-circle12 sk-child"></div> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://widget.intercom.io/widget/{app_id}"></script><script src="https://drrjhlchpvi7e.cloudfront.net/libs/stamplay-js-sdk/1.3.3/stamplay.min.js"></script> <script src="scripts/vendor.11815825.js"></script> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-i18n/1.5.0/angular-locale_nl-nl.js"></script> <script src="scripts/scripts.9367f845.js"></script> <!-- Snippet for Intercom.io --> <script type="text/javascript">(function(){var w=window;var ic=w.Intercom;if(typeof ic==="function"){ic('reattach_activator');ic('update',intercomSettings);}else{var d=document;var i=function(){i.c(arguments)};i.q=[];i.c=function(args){i.q.push(args)};w.Intercom=i;function l(){var s=d.createElement('script');s.type='text/javascript';s.async=true;
s.src='https://widget.intercom.io/widget/{app_id}';
var x=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];x.parentNode.insertBefore(s,x);}if(w.attachEvent){w.attachEvent('onload',l);}else{w.addEventListener('load',l,false);}}})()</script>  </body>
```

As shown in the output of terminal **ui-view** don't have any content.
 Don't know why this strange behavior occurs every time. So can any body please guide me how can I get ng-view content if ng-app is defined on body not as HTML tag?

Comment: What version of phantomjs are you using? and do you get the expected result if you sleep a few seconds between the `visit` and `puts`?

Comment: Using PhantomJS 1.9.8 and sleep also not working for this.

Comment: Phantomjs 1.9.8 is basically equivalent to Safari 5 and really outdated.  It doesn't provide Function.prototype.bind() which is required by angular - if you hadn't set js_errors to false in your driver config you would see an error.  Upgrade to phantomjs 2.1+

Comment: Yeah that's worked for me. phantomjs 2.1.1 is working properly for me. Thanks

Comment: I added it as an answer for you to accept so the question can be marked as complete

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to PhantomJS 2.1+ which supports Function.prototype.bind() as required by Angular.